# Capitalize first character in multiple dataframe columns

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below. How can I convert the string found in x columns of data to create the data1 dataframe.

```
data <- data.frame(c("YES", "NO", "MAYBE"))
data <- cbind(data, data, data)
x <- c(1, 2)

data1 <- structure(list(c..Yes....No....Maybe.. = c("Yes", "No", "Maybe"
), c..Yes....No....Maybe.. = c("Yes", "No", "Maybe"), c..YES....NO....MAYBE.. = c("YES", 
"NO", "MAYBE")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a function taken from the helpfile for [`?tolower`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chartr.html)

```
capwords <- function(s, strict = FALSE) {
    cap <- function(s) paste(toupper(substring(s, 1, 1)),
                  {s <- substring(s, 2); if(strict) tolower(s) else s},
                             sep = "", collapse = " " )
    sapply(strsplit(s, split = " "), cap, USE.NAMES = !is.null(names(s)))
}
```

Which will capitalize the first character of each word found in a string. Then apply this to your data

```
cbind(as.data.frame(apply(data[,x], 2, capwords, strict = TRUE)), data[,-x])

#   c..YES....NO....MAYBE.. c..YES....NO....MAYBE...1 data[, -x]
# 1                     Yes                       Yes        YES
# 2                      No                        No         NO
# 3                   Maybe                     Maybe      MAYBE
```

Using [`dplyr::mutate_at`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) would be even better, IMO. But it's important that your character columns are stored as characters **and not as factors**. Additionally, the column names need to be unique.

```
data <- data.frame(a=c("YES", "NO", "MAYBE"),
                   b=c("YES", "NO", "MAYBE"),
                   c=c("YES", "NO", "MAYBE"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dplyr::mutate_at(data, x, capwords, strict = TRUE)

#       a     b     c
# 1   Yes   Yes   YES
# 2    No    No    NO
# 3 Maybe Maybe MAYBE
```

Comment: Sorry for late, response, but this worked. Thank you!